# Get click position over command binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

What I want to do is a UserControl containing a section with a grid, where something happens when clicking on the grid. I need the position of the pixel where the click happened and I'm doing all of this MVVM style.
I know how I can prompt actions on my ViewModel:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.InputBindings>
   <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding MinimapClick}"/>
 </Grid.InputBindings>
</Grid>
```

My problem is now that I don't know how to retrieve the Coordinates... any ideas?
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```cs
private void MinimapClick(object parameter)
{
    Point mousePos = Mouse.GetPosition(myWindow);
}
```

If you don't have a reference to the window you could send it as a parameter (or use whatever reference point you want).

Comment: Good idea! That got me on the right way... I'll elaborate on my solution in my answer a bit more. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14):

KDiTraglia had [the right pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642787/3195477) for me...
In any case I had some issues with defining the actions and binding to my ViewModel. I'll post my solution in case someone else has some problems. Here's what I've done in the xaml:

```
<Grid Width="100" Height="100" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="TargetGrid">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding Path=TargetClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TargetGrid}" />
        </Grid.InputBindings>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I create the UserControl and bind it to the ViewModel. In the ViewModel I implement and create the following command:

```
public class PositioningCommand : ICommand
{
    public PositioningCommand()
    {
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Point mousePos = Mouse.GetPosition((IInputElement)parameter);
        Console.WriteLine("Position: " + mousePos.ToString());
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}

public PositioningCommand TargetClick
{
    get;
    internal set;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This was an outstanding answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a related issue - I wanted to capture the mouse position for click events for my **ContextMenu**. Problem: my menu's *parent* (an image control) was not recognized by the CommandParameter ElementName.

For reference, the binding error I received, *prior* to adding my menu to the namespace, was:

```
    System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=imgArena'. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name='mnuAddItem'); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')
```

Apparently WPF context menus belong to a different visual tree than your control, making binding quite frustrating.

After some research, I found this simple fix, which I placed in the constructor for my code behind:

```
    NameScope.SetNameScope(mnuGrid, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));
```

Where "mnuGrid" is the name of my context menu.

After I did this, I was able to pass my control as a parameter to my command exactly as Beta Vulgaris did above.

For reference, my XAML looks like this:

```
    <Image Name="imgArena" >
        <Image.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="mnuGrid">
                <MenuItem Header="Place _Entry" Name="mnuAddItem"
                    Command="{Binding AddEntryCmd}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=imgArena}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        <Image.ContextMenu>
    </Image>
```

Comment: Edit: I thought that would work, but unfortunately, the X and Y coordinates are relative to the *last* click event, which happens to be on my context menu, not on the image where I right-clicked to launch the context menu.

Comment: I know this is late but...you could invoke a command on right click of the image that sends the mouse coordinates and saves them in a variable, and then use those saved coordinates if your AddEntryCmd gets fired.